# Android Gridview spacing and/or centering not working as intended

Tags: android, gridview

I have a problem with spacing in my Android app: Unwanted space between columns.

I noticed similar questions have been asked on stackoverflow before, but none seemed to match exactly my case.

Here's what it looks like (using the code below)... https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjyDD.png

From my PlayAdapter.java

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context1);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(images[index]);
        return imageView;
    }
```

From my Spacing.java

```
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview2);
    final PlayAdapter PlayAdapter1 = new PlayAdapter(this, images);
    gridView.setAdapter(PlayAdapter1);
    gridView.setNumColumns(numCols);
    gridView.setColumnWidth(width);
```

(numCols and width are determined programmatically elsewhere )

The GridView:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/gridview2"
android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform">
</GridView>
```

So, if stretchMode is set to "columnWidth", "spacingWidth" or 
"spacingWidthUniform" there is too much space between 
the columns of the grid. See the imgur link above for the result.

Here's a solution I already tried instead:

If stretchMode is changed to "none", the grid is centered 
vertically in portrait mode, but not horizontally in 
landscape mode. Looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/11ngz.png

Changing the settings for gravity and
layout_gravity did not help, nor did making a LinearLayout
around the gridview.

Any other ideas what to do?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?  Having the same problem.